# jQuery not working on page load in an Apache Cordova application

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm using jQuery to fill a circle with percentage, it seems to work perfectly fine on my test page and it works fine with the debugger placed after document.ready on my main page. Whenever I remove the debugger and run it as is, it doesn't seem to work. I'm using visual studio and running the application with Task Runner Explorer using serve and then serve-dist to check later on.

Here is the test page where it seems to be working fine on page load and refresh

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {



            var $that = $(this);
            var percentage = '70'; 

            //$that.attr('data-fill');
            //alert(percentage);

            setTimeout(function () {
                animate($that, percentage)
            }, 400);

            $('.fill').load('click', function () {
                var $that = $(this);
                var percentage = $that.attr('data-fill');
                //alert(percentage);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    animate($that, percentage)
                }, 400);
            });

            function animate($that, percentage) {
                if (!$that.hasClass('fill')) return;
                $that.removeClass('fill');

                percentage = (100 - percentage) || 0;
                var percentage_initial = 100,
                    percentage_current = percentage_initial,
                    interval = 0.5;

                var interval_gradient = setInterval(function () {
                    $that.css(
                      'background',
                      'linear-gradient(lightblue ' + percentage_current + '%,orange ' + percentage_current + '%)'
                    );
                    percentage_current -= interval;
                    if (percentage_current <= percentage) clearInterval(interval_gradient);
                }, 5);

                $that.addClass('filled');
            };
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        * {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background: #222;
        }

        .circle {
            width: 170px;
            height: 170px;
            margin-left: 0;
            border: 5px solid black;
            border-radius: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            background-color: lightblue;
            text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.7);
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -moz-align-items: center;
            -ms-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .circle-text {
            font-size: 48px;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-weight: 250;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .example {
            background: linear-gradient(lightblue 34%, orange 34%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="circle fill" data-fill="70">
        <p class="circle-text">70%</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script which I'm using on the page in the Apache Cordova application

```
<div class="page page-dashboard page-top" data-ng-controller="UserDashboardCtrl">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('.fill').load('click', function () {
                var $that = $(this);
                var balancePoints = $that.attr('data-fill');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    animate($that, balancePoints)
                }, 400);
            });

            function animate($that, balancePoints) {

                if (!$that.hasClass('fill')) return;
                $that.removeClass('fill');
                var totalPoints = 100;

                balancePoints = (totalPoints - balancePoints) || 0;
                var percentage_initial = 100,
                    percentage_current = percentage_initial,
                    interval = 0.5;

                var interval_gradient = setInterval(function () {
                    $that.css(
                      'background',
                      'linear-gradient(white ' + percentage_current + '%,orange ' + percentage_current + '%)'
                    );
                    percentage_current -= interval;
                    if (percentage_current <= balancePoints) clearInterval(interval_gradient);
                }, 5);

                $that.addClass('filled');
            };
        });


    </script>

    <style>
        * {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background: #222;
        }

        .circle {
            width: 170px;
            height: 170px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 5px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            /*text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.7);*/
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -moz-align-items: center;
            -ms-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .circle-text {
            font-size: 48px;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-weight: 250;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .example {
            background: linear-gradient(white 34%, orange 34%);
        }
    </style>
<div class="row">
// Body continues for the page below where it is called in a div same as the above example
```

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery shortcut function `$(document).ready()` fires on the `DOMContentLoaded` event in the browser, however in a Cordova environment, you need to wait for `deviceready` which fires when the Cordova environment has finished initialising. It's working when you pause execution with a debugger breakpoint because this is delaying execution sufficiently for Cordova to have finished initialising concurrently when you resume execution from the debugger.

TL;DR: Change it to:

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function () {
  console.log('deviceready');
  // etc.
```